# Use sp_DatabaseRestore for restore when database does not exist

Tags: sql-server, restore

I am trying to use `sp_DatabaseRestore` from the **SQL Server First Responder Kit** to restore some databases. It works fine if I first restore the database in a normal way using SSMS, but if the database does not previously exist, it says that it could not find the file specified (for both data an log-files).

It also ends with the following message:

> The database "DatabaseName" does not exist. RESTORE can only create a database when restoring either a full backup or a file backup of the primary file.

But the first path is for the full backup, so I am not sure what this means.

Is there some particular use of the parameters that would help me use this even when the database does not exist, or am I forced to create them first?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Edit:
Code that is used (paths and names have been changed). The code fails if the database does not exist. If I create the database, then it works:

```
DECLARE @VersionDate datetime;
EXEC dbo.sp_DatabaseRestore @Database = N'DatabaseName',                                
                            @BackupPathFull = N'\\SERVERNAME\Backup\servername-wfcs$ServerNameAG01\DatabaseName\FULL\',            
                            @BackupPathLog = N'\\SERVERNAME\Backup\servername-wfcs$ServerNameAG01\DatabaseName\LOG\',             
                            @MoveFiles = 0,                
                            @ContinueLogs = 0,             
                            @RunRecovery = 1,              
                            @ForceSimpleRecovery = 0,
                            @Debug = 0,
                            @VersionDate = @VersionDate OUTPUT
```

Edit 2: Turns out there was a difference in the data-file folder names between the old and the new server. The old server had a version-number lower than the actual version of the SQL Server, probably due to an earlier in place upgrade. When trying to restore from a backup with correct data folder, there is no problem.

Comment: The first googled link has an answer: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/databaserestore-open-source-database-restore-stored-procedure/

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Thanks for your comment. However I have read that documentation already (and once again now), and I can't really find anything there that answers my question. If you found the answer in there, I would appreciate it if you could narrow it down for me where to look in that link.

Comment: Can you post the command you're using now that isn't working?

Comment: Specify variables MoveFiles =  1, MoveDataDrive = YourDataLocation  and MoveLogDrive = YourLogLocation" - I believe it should help

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Hi Erik, I edited my post and added the code.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I have not tried that. I thought it would use the default location from backup if the MoveFiles was not specified. I will give it a try.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I tried your suggestion Denis, it seemed to do the trick. Thank you. If you want to make your comment into an answer, I can mark it.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Hi, this one seems to be an oversight by me: turns out that the path for data-files on the new server had changed slightly...the version number folder was not the same. Tested out on a backup that has the same data-folder, and then it works. Just in case you guys started looking for bugs... will edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a difference in the data-file folder names between the old and the new server. The old server had a version-number lower than the actual version of the SQL Server, probably due to an earlier in place upgrade. When trying to restore from a backup with correct data folder, there is no problem.